# Scala: library to get geohashes from WKT linestring

Tags: java, scala, geospatial, geohashing

I have a WKT Linestring, let's say:

```
LINESTRING (11.782009 42.099761, 11.781858 42.099615, 11.782359 42.100029)
```

From this path, I want to get the list of geohashes that it goes through.

In python, there is https://github.com/mathieuripert/geoh . A Java equivalent is https://github.com/jillesvangurp/geogeometry however this library is buggy (it doesn't use the provided precision and somewhere it inverts lat and lon so that the resulting geohashes are wrong). I prefer not to fork it as I am not an expert in spatial processing.

I can't find the same function in geomesa or jts, do you know any reliable library that does the job?

Comment: Have you tried [GeoHash from GeoMesa](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/master/geomesa-utils/src/main/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/utils/geohash/GeoHash.scala) ?

Comment: Geohashes are to be put in elasticsearch, for better query performance.

Comment: in GeoMesa, I can't find any method to apply to a list of coordinates, only to get a single GeoHash. Or is there any?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found GeohashUtils.decomposeGeometry() in https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/master/geomesa-utils/src/main/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/utils/geohash/GeoHash.scala as suggested